# Suggestion for Multi-protocol Network traffic generator software

Tags: network-monitor, http

I am looking for Network traffic/Packet generator for different protocols. I am using iperf for TCP and UDP but I am looking for something more reliable. Also I need to generate a traffic upto 10 GBbps for other protocols like HTTP/SMTP. I am willing to spend some money too if no open source is available. Also I am not sure if I can achieve this without H/W support.

OS Preference : Ubuntu/Windows with IPV4 support.

Answer (score 1):

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is a python tool that can generate just about any traffic that you need but if your hardware is not up to it then you will hit limits.

- Free.
- Scriptable'
- Just about any packet that you can think of, including malformed packets.
- Flood and Attack testing.
- Cross platform including Linux.
- Python based.
- The only downside is that you need a fair knowledge of the protocols that you are trying to create.

It is also worth talking a look at [The Very Unofficial Beginners Guide to Scapy](http://theitgeekchronicles.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/scapyguide1.pdf).